# Trigger php function from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, facebook-like

I am trying to individually track the number of people who liked my facebook page from a particular webpage. For that I am using FB event. I wish to save the counts to my local database.

Below is the code that I have been trying out. But it is not working.

```
<?php
echo "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:fb=\"http://    www.facebook.com/2008/fbml\">";

echo "<head>";
echo "<script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js\"></script>";
echo "<script src=\"http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=157605600977665&amp;xfbml=1\"></script>";
echo "<script>";

echo "var a = 0;";
echo "$(\"document\").ready(function(){";
echo "FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {";
//not working
echo "window.location=\"1.php?action=add";
echo "});";
echo "});";
echo "</script>";
echo "</head>";

echo "<body>";

if ($action=="add") 
{ 
mysql_query("update likes set count = count + 1 where id=1;");
} 

echo "<div id=\"fb-root\"></div>";
echo "<fb:like href=\"http://www.facebook.com\" send=\"false\" width=\"450\" show_faces=\"false\"></fb:like> <br/>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";

?>
```

Comment: What doesnt work ? does the event get fired ?

Comment: `"window.location=\"1.php?action=add";` <- thats not correct the string passed to window.location should be enclosed by quotes ie you missed the closing quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the $_GET variable which will contain any url parameters.

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) {
   $action = $_GET['action'];
   if ($action == "add") {
     mysql_query("update likes set count = count + 1 where id=1;");
   } 
} // untested, should work though
```

Also by the way, you don't have to echo out all your HTML. You could open and close the PHP tags anytime you want.

```
<html>
<head>
....etc...

<?php
  // do work here
?>

.... more html ...
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick replies. I edited as you had mentioned. But, there is parse error. 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp\www\Counter\1.php on line 28